# How to write a txt file from the contents of a ScrolledText Widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a coding language in python and  I want to be able to write code into a ScrolledText widget, click a save button in a menubar and then get os to write a file containing whats in the ScrolledText Widget

I've already tried multiple variations of the `.get()` function (including `.get('1.0', END)` but they all come back with the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

```py
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()

shell = ScrolledText(root, width=167, height=42).grid(column=0, row=1)

def save():
   file = open("code.txt", "x")
   file.write(shell.get("1.0", END))
   file.close()
```

I want the result to be like:
file.write(shell.get(FIXED .GET CODE))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `shell` isn't assigned the `ScrolledText` object, but rather the result of the call to that object's `grid` method. So, as the error output suggests, `shell` is `None`. If you assign the object to `shell` and then call `shell.grid` things should work out the way you want.